# What is this popup object called in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad

What is the pop-up object used in the Apple's "Clock" app for iPad called?

The popup looks similar to a MapKit callout, but often comes out of the side of a clicked button. Apple uses the pop-up often to display pickerViews on iPad. I am wanting to use it also for iPad applications in Swift, but I cannot find the name anywhere in documentation or on StackOverflow--because I don't know what it is called and it is thus hard to find.

I already know that some may not like the simplicity of this question, but I have seriously tried and have looked through books and other documentation trying to identify what the name of it, but it is so hard to find it without knowing the name! (I've included an image of the object just to be clear, but, unfortunately, I don't have the 'reputation' for the image to show up automatically in StackOverflow)

[Image: The Object/PopUp item used in the "Clock" App.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koifc.png)

Comment: It's called a popover

Comment: Thank you, Dan, that does seem correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is a Popover, as identified by Dan.

Thank you those who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

You must be talking about UIDatePicker.

Comment: Well, I meant the container with the UIDatePicker, which I think Dan correctly identified as a "Popover".